# In rails admin, how to remember record list filter condition that user last added site:stackoverflow.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I added some filter condition to list a part of records, then jump to other page to do something else, but when I come back the records list page, I have to add same condition again. Is there any way to remember the conditions that I added at the last time?

Answer (score 0):

If the condition is "stable" meaning it can hardcoded on the code, you can add a scope to the list

```
rails_admin do
  list do
    scopes [ :your_scope ]
  end
end
```

If that does not work for you, you'll need to modify the gem again, i can only point you to the this file:

```
lib/rails_admin/config/actions/index.rb
```

You'll have or override that file on your project or fork rails_admin, specifically the params[:scope] will hold the conditions you want to save, you could use request.session to populate it, just an idea.